# Batch Job Completes, but does not update records

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I have a batch job that runs every day at 3am that I invoke through Execute Anonymous window in the developer console. It had been working correctly until we made a change to the query's filter criteria in the WHERE clause. The schedule works correctly, and the job completes (added debugging to confirm), but none of the records are updated.

I am thinking that it has something to do with the order of execution because the field in the WHERE clause is a formula field. Would that be the reason? Can someone help me understand why it's not updating any records? Thank you!

**Batch Class:**

```
        global class BatchQuotaRealign implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
    {
        global Database.Querylocator start(Database.Batchablecontext BC)
        {       
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,User__c,OwnerId,Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c FROM Quota__c WHERE Valid_Quota_Owner_Realignment__c = true]);
        }

    global void execute(Database.Batchablecontext BC, list<SObject> scope)
    {
        list<Quota__c> DeskQuotasToBeUpdated = new list<Quota__c>();
        for(sObject ca : scope)
        {
            Quota__c qu = ((Quota__c)ca);
            qu.User__c = qu.Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c;
            qu.OwnerId = qu.Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c;
            DeskQuotasToBeUpdated.add(qu);
            System.debug('Desk Quota To Be Updated List: ' + DeskQuotasToBeUpdated);
        }
        try
        {
            //system.Debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, METHODNAME + ' :: Updating '+ DeskQuotasToBeUpdated.size() +' Desk Quotas now.\n\n');
            Database.update(DeskQuotasToBeUpdated,false);
        }
        catch(DMLException dmle)
        {            
            for (Integer i=0; i < dmle.getNumDml(); i++)
            {
                system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'\n' + dmle.getDmlMessage(i) + '\n');
            }
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' :: ******************************** DML EXCEPTION END ********************************\n');

            throw dmle;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    global void finish (Database.Batchablecontext BC)
    {
        System.debug('Batch Quota Realign completed successfully!');
    }
}
```

**Schedulable Class:**

```
global class BatchQuotaRealignSchedulable implements Schedulable
{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
        // the argument has to be a class that implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
        Id batchProcessId = Database.ExecuteBatch(new BatchQuotaRealign());
   }

}
```

**Execute Anonymous to Schedule the Job Every Day at 3am:**

```
BatchQuotaRealignSchedulable obj = new BatchQuotaRealignSchedulable();
String jobName = 'QuotaRealign-Nightly';
String sched = '0 0 3 ? * *';  // use "?" for either dayofMonth or dayofWeek - cannot specify both
system.schedule(jobName, sched, obj);
```

Comment: A partial update will never throw a `DMLException` fyi. You're basically swallowing the exception silently here. You should replace all that `try`/`catch` nonsense with a plain old `update` and then you will see which batches fail.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you can update `scope` directly. There's no need to go through all that extra effort. Just change `list<sobject>` in your parameter list to `list<quota__c>`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have removed the try/catch portion, but I'm still not getting any errors. None of the records are getting updated either though. Do you have any suggestions on how else I could debug this issue?